# Tag a video while uploading it with Facebook's Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

So the video's uploading great using the new video POST support in Graph API from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/.
The title and description fields work well too. However, how do you set tags?

Something similar to photo tags has been tried. Like a simple dictionary made of tag_uid keys and their values.
Is it not supported to set tags yet? If it is, what's missing?